# Detect Google Earth is installed in a web page on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-earth

Is it possible in web page on Internet Explorer to detect if the Google Earth application is installed on the client machine using Javascript?

This page is part of a Trusted Site on an intranet.

Update: detecting it via creating an ActiveX object or any IE specific javascript is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this works using Javascript. I'm pretty sure Google Earth doesn't install a plugin into Internet Explorer (or any other browser for that matter). So you can forget Javascript.

As you are on a trusted site you may try using ActiveX. I'm not into ActiveX but maybe there's a way to have a deeper look into the client's system.

Answer (score 5):

yes it is possible - on your html page you call the init function for the API

```
<body onload="init()">
   bla bla bla 
</body>
```

In a JavaScript, when creating a GE instance for your page, you provide a function pointer for a callback function called on errors

```
function init()
{
    if (ge == null)
    {
        google.earth.createInstance("content", initCallback, failureCallback);
    }
}
```

finally - in that function you check the error code

```
function failureCallback(errorCode)
{
    if (errorCode == "ERR_CREATE_PLUGIN") {
        alert("Plugin not installed")
    } else {
        alert("Other failure loading the Google Earth Plugin: " + errorCode);
    }
}
```

look at [this](http://www.dauda.at/locator) for a complete working code.

Good luck
MikeD

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to detect the GE plugin. Does that get installed when you install regular GE? Regular GE is what I want to detect is installed.

Matthew

Comment: oops sorry - seems I misinterpreted your questions

yes - this detects the GE API plugin
no - this does not detect if a regular GE is installed
no - the GE plugin is not installed when you install regular GE